# Is the neutral outside of the plug dangerous while carrying current?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I accidentally bought bulbs that has too long of a stem for my bathroom vanity. It also has a very larger upper region that makes it very touchable. How dangerous is this metal area that is exposed when the power is on? Is this safe to use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: the 60-hertz flicker on those bulbs would kill me long before the exposed contacts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you cannot be sure that the stem is connected to the neutral wire and not to the live one unless you test it with a testing screwdriver, since alternating current is bidirectional.

Even if we consider it to be the neutral one you cannot trust that it is safe to touch. In ideal circumstances, where the neutral wire is very well grounded, it shouldn't have an electric potential. However, if there is any problem with the wiring or grounding, now or in the future, it could be dangerous, if touched.

I would suggest to cover it with some insulating tape.

Comment: In the UK, depending on how the house is grounded, the neutral can be 50+V from ground.  (That would correspond to about 25+V in the US.)  Admittedly *most* houses have grounds bonded to the incoming neutral, which means the neutral is within a few volts of ground.

Answer (score 1):

It is dangerous when the circuit is live, as it is carrying mains power. It could also be dangerous when the circuit is off, as there's always the possibility that something was wired backwards.

Comment: If wired correctly, and depending on the grounding used, it should normally be safe even when the power is on.  It will only be at a few volts above ground.  However, it can be many tens of volts.